# How to download svg-captcha dataset as image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, captcha

I am using npm module svg-captcha for generating captcha. When ever we create a new captcha we get a data-set containing

```
{
  isMath: false,           // if true will be a simple math equation
  useFont: null,          // Can be path to ttf/otf font file
  size: 5,                // number of characters for string capthca
  ignoreChars: '0o1i',    // characters to not include in string capthca
  noise: 3,               // number of noise lines
  color: true,            // if true noise lines and captcha characters will be randomly colored
                          // (is set to true if background is set)
  background: null,       // HEX or RGB(a) value for background set to null for transparent
  width: 150,             // width of captcha
  height: 50,             // height of captcha
  fontSize: 56,           // font size for captcha
  charPreset: null,       // string of characters for use with string captcha set to null for default aA-zZ

}
```

When I render this in html as image, I can see the image

```
app.get('/captcha', captcha.generate())

    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
      res.type('html')
      res.end(`
        <img src="/captcha"/>

        <form action="/test" method="post">

          <input type="text" name="captcha"/>

          <input type="submit"/>

        </form>
      `)
    })
```

How can we save this '/captcha' as image?

Answer (score 1):

Here, the captcha we get when we say captcha.generate() contains data and text.

var new_Captcha=captcha.generate()

new_Captcha:{"text":"some captcha value (Ex:AuEr)","data":`<svg>... </svg>`}

As data we get is in html we need to convert this html to url usinf Base64 converter for that we can you `btoa`(In-built function in javascript)

Append the above encoded Base64 string to `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` and we get the url which on browser renders the image. Making use of this url we can download the image.